# Play 1.2.4 CRUD error: Model not managed by any plugin

Tags: java, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I am implementing the CRUD module.

I have a composite primary key in my DB table. I implemented it in model class using @EmbeddedID annotation. Hence the primary keys are places in a single java file and in the other file the annotation is used to use that java class containing the primary keys.

When click the "New User" button, I am getting an error:

`Unexpected error: Model is not manager by any plugin`

where the "model" is referred as the java class where the primary keys are present.

Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `@Entity` annotation on model class definition

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {}
```